# Создание бота

Tags: python

Как мне написать бота для сайта, который добавляет много людей в список друзей?

Answer (score 2):

- [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/): реализует программный просмотр страниц с сохранением состояния.
- [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/): используется для сканирования веб-сайтов и извлечения структурированных данных из страницах.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот эту штуку - http://sikuli.org/